# Grub menu resets after using ubuntu in dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, shutdown, windows-10

I have Ubuntu on the computer disk and Windows 10 on external disk. I used `boot-repair` in order to show Windows 10 on the grub menu and it worked. The problem is that when I use Ubuntu - the grub menu resets so I can't see the Windows item in the list after a shutdown and I need to use `boot-repair` again.

I've noticed that when I use ubuntu and plug in Windows disk and then shutdown, then everything is ok. So I think that the grub updates on each shutdown.

If I guessed correctly, is there a way to make it not update on shutdown? if not, is there any other solution?

EDIT:
My guess is wrong, the grub doesn't update when shutting down, probably something else that I do resets it somehow.

EDIT 2 - link to boot info summary:
http://sprunge.us/wbhn64

Comment: Please add a link to your boot info summary created by boot repair.

Comment: I didn't save the summary, so I tried to shutdown and use boot repair again but now I see that my guess was wrong, the grub menu doesn't reset when shutting down. so it's probably something else i normally  do that resets it somehow. so for now it doesn't change but I'm sure it will happen in the near future. Does it matter if I use boot repair now when it's working normally or should I wait till it isn't working before getting the summary?

Comment: You can use boot repair to only create the boot info summary and do nothing else.

Comment: How do I do that? do I need to boot into the live-usb?

Comment: You can do that from your installed system, no need to boot the live-usb.

Comment: edited with the summary